# Database Design - Employee Clocking In and Out System

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, logic

I want to develop Employee Clocking In and Out System (website).

I am concerned two things:

- If staff forgot to 'Clock Out' from yesterday and they have 'Clock In' today, it should flag to the manager.
- Staff may work over time, eg: Clock In Monday 11:00 AM To Tuesday 01:30 AM (after Midnight). I dont want system think thay staff have forgot to clock Out..

  - Staff may clock In and Clock Out multiple times a day.

How to solve this issue and what can be improved on Database Design?

**staff table:**

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name        | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| password    | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| hourly_rate | decimal(6,2) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**clocking table:**

```
+----------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| staff_id       | int(11)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| clock_in_date  | datetime | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| clock_out_date | datetime | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 5):

What a massive can of worms you're opening here mate. After working for a company that only does clocking systems it is something I will never want to do again!

I realize my reply is greatly conceptual and addresses a few matters outside the normal scope of the question but this is in order to outline database design and structural concepts in this type of application. This information comes from recent specialist development I have done in this area also so it is not solely hypothetical but proven in practice.

When you're looking at this type of system you're best to initially use indicators as flags, this is generally the quantity of punches versus comparing every record. To compare every record for 1,000 employees is not the best thing!

For example, if the user has in a 24 hour period 8 punches (start of day, morning break start, morning break end, lunch start, lunch end, afternoon break start, afternoon break end and end of day) you can determine that it was unlikely there was no missed punches in the period and overtime has occurred, however if there were 7 punches in the 24 hour period (start of day, morning break start, morning break end, lunch start, lunch end, afternoon break start and end of day) you know that a punch is missing and the person forgot to clock out for the day. Notice how afternoon break end is not there.

However this is not full-proof and only provides an indicative reference, you will need to compare a shift schedule to punches to make sure nothing was actually missed. Because it is possible that both lunch end and afternoon break end were both missed leaving 6 punches you can set up your code to flag anything that is not X number of punches for that employee. When flagged you then run your actual comparison on that employee for that period to work out what has actually happened and what was missed.

This doesn't mean you don't compare all records, the thing is however depending on the number of employees it could cause some big problems doing exact comparison on every record, this is where it is generally better for larger numbers of employees to use 2 servers, 1 for data collection and interface only, the second for running comparison processes.

As I mentioned, for this type of application and to work with varying schedules, you also need to look at holding shift schedules to compare against. You will want to hold a padding record for each employee that will give equal time before a shift start and after a shift end. This will mean the likelihoods of overtime extending past 1 time period will be minimal. The basic formular is really simple: number of hours in the shift - 24 hours / 2 = time padding

You now place the time padding before and after the shift schedule for that user. But you still need to handle a shift swap, change or more than a 24-hour shift. This is where it really gets tricky. You will want to look at holding a table of overlapping times (padding, shift and punches) that can then be reconciled against any future adjustments to the schedules as after the fact changes are not uncommon in time attendance.

Now you will also want to hold a table of absentee periods for sick leave and holidays, this data will then need to be flagged generally within the punch-in/punch-out table as this is what you compare with. When a flag is set for a period the record can be skipped in comparison and a note left on the reporting without needing to run additional operations to check it.

Almost at th end, notice how you need to forget about your normal date/time conventions to measure this for a range of variables? Not to mention to work effectively and efficiently over multiple dates? Because of this you are generally best to only work with start and end times by dd/mm/YYYY hh:mm:ss, for the measurements use UNIX time to calculate how much time has elapsed. In saying that to be audit able most systems do need a "date stamp" record so server side processing of this is likely to be required when putting out reports.

Finally, I would also recommend holding a results table, this would give the reporting results for each user, this way when you want to provide historical records you can dynamically generate documents however you don't have to waste processing power on comparing records every time a report is requested.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

This is not completely correct from domain point of view.

Clock ins or outs / punches are needed for audit purposes or troubleshooting.
So, You need to store individual punches history for all employees.

The clocking table in your case could be a derived data.

The clocking table should be

```
+----------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| staff_id       | int(11)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| clock_type     | int(1)   | NO   |     | 0       | 0-in, 1-out    |
| clock          | datetime | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: This would add needless complexity to figuring out if the person had clocked out before clocking in again. The original design is better. EAV tables should be avoided whereever they can be avoided.

Comment: No, the original one gets super complicated, am telling that from experience.  Any novice goes for the original design, failing to note that db is not supposed to give you reports of your wish but to provide data in least redundant form.  You may keep a redundant table of consolidated report (in-out) for quick retrieval.

Comment: @shikhar You may be just right. Have a look at this question I've posted. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12632302/design-to-represent-employee-check-in-and-check-out

Answer (score 2):

I don't really see a problem with your design as much as I see a problem with the poorly deifned requirements. You need a better definition of when the manager gets altered to account for the shifts that go over multiple days. Perhaps the best rule would be that if someone has not clocked out for 24 hours or if they try to clock in a second time, the supervisor gets notified.  You may also need a trigger on the database that will not allow a clock in if there is a missing clock out. Or you may allow the clock in and send the clockout that is missing to the supervisor for action.

One thing you especially need is auditing (a separate table) so that you can see who changed records when. YOu awnt to be able to tell who changed the record and what the old value was in case of questions about someone's time.

Time clocking (and I assume they will get paid based on clocked hours) is an activity that needs serious internal controls (at the database level not inthe application! Internal controls must never be at the application level if you are trying to prevent fraud.) No one should have direct access to the table. They should only be able to change through a stored procedure that dictates exactly what they can do.

You may want to have specific rules for supervisors vice non-supervisors. Generally anything time-related should only be allowed to be changed by a supervisor of the person after the fact. I would have a trigger that enforces this, the person entering the timesheet should only be allowed to change the clock in data and then only if it is null. All other changes should be from a supervisor of the person. So you might need a table to store teh organization structure or at least a field that shows who the staff person's supervisior is.

If people are going to be poaid based on clock ins and oputs, thenyou might want to check with your accounting people and their auditors beofre finalizing the business rules. Internal controal for this sort of thing can be very complex and tricky to get correct.

One design problem I see is the hourly rate column, this changes over time and you will want to be able to tell that (espcially if the rate changes in the middle of a payperiod for some reason), so I would break this out to a related table. Again, the rights to this table need to be strictly enforced. No one excpt an HR person should be able to enter data into the hourly rate field.

Answer (score 1):

Your database design seems fine. It should only record in and out times. Somewhere else in your application you should program your business rules. [You may read this article on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) on separation of concerns.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to allow `NULL` on `clock_out_date`. That way, you can record a check in at the time it occurs and simply leave the `clock_out_date` `NULL` to indicate that the user hasn't checked out yet.

If you plan on supporting multiple-check in/outs per event/day, then you will also need an event/day ID column in the clocking table so that you can group the checkins by event/day. As you noted, the date can't be used for grouping checkins that span midnight. We use an event_id, but perhaps you want a payroll_date.

I am using the same clocking table structure for a similar system. It's been in production for a year, and I wouldn't change a thing. We store all times in UTC.

Note that we do NOT use this system for payroll, and there may be significant auditing requirements for a payroll system.

Comment: Similarly Clock-in date should never be allowed to be null

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Sometime staff might check in & outs per day (any random reasons) - so you mean I need to add `week_day` field? also what about staff may work over time, eg: Clock In Monday 11:00 AM To Tuesday 01:30 AM (after Midnight). How would that work.

Comment: You'd probably have some algorithm that calculates what the payroll date is, though for a shop that's open 24 hours, you might need to tie it to an individual's schedule.