# Design to represent employee check-in and check-out

Tags: mysql, database-design

I currently have a table which represents the start and stop work times of an employee:

- id_employee int
- check_in datetime
- check_out datetime

It requires an update on check_out when the employee is finished.

Would it be preferable to have a table as follows ?

- id_employee int
- date_event datetime
- event_type varchar, values can be CHECKIN or CHECKOUT.

To determine if an employee has already checked in all I have to is check if the last record for a given employee has an event_type of CHECKIN. Also, fetching a record and updating it is no longer necessary.

Is the second approach better ? Or do you have other suggestions ?

Comment: If you do go with the second option, use `ENUM('CHECKIN', 'CHECKOUT')` for the event_type column.  It is much smaller and makes it easier to use a fixed table format, which offers better performance than a dynamic table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As usual, "it depends".

Option 1 is easier to build, and simpler to query. Finding out who checked in but didn't check out is a simple query; finding the total hours worked for each employee is also straightforward. This simplicity probably means it will be faster for common queries. The only drawback I see is that it is harder to extend. If you want to capture a different event type for "lunch break", for instance, you have to add extra columns.

Option 2 is more flexible - you can add new event types without changing your schema. However, simple queries - how many hours did employee x work in June - are quite tricky. You pay for the flexibility in significant additional effort.

So, it depends what you mean by "better".

Comment: "Better" as in what would a demi-god of database design would do. Thinking along the lines of the three NFs :) . Flexibility was considered. Now you mention it, calculation of hours would be messy. Another possible drawback is if values need to be mapped to objects though.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that a "demi-god" of database design would come up with a solution that meets the current and known future requirements as simply as possible; if you don't need to extend the application with different types of event, go with option 1. It's easier to work with, and nobody is handing out prizes for "elegant database design".

Comment: just keep in mind that you will probably (in the future, if it hasn't already been established) need a way for managers to "fix" time entries.  For instance, if an employee clocks in at 8am and then out at 5pm but did take a break but never clocked in/out for it, you'll have to have a way for a manager to insert the break from 12pm to 1pm.  With the first design, you'd have to change the record with 5pm to 12pm, then enter a new record from 1pm to 5pm.  That's why I prefer option 2; you would just need to insert 2 punches and let your application logic handle the calculations / sorting.

Answer (score 9):

I know this post is outdated but, this is for someone who's still looking for solution:

**Attendance Table Structure**

```
id              | int
employee_code   | varchar
status          | enum('check_in','check_out')
created         | datetime
```

**Data**

```
id  employee_code   status          created

1   EMP0001         check_in        2016-08-20 09:30:30
2   EMP0001         check_out       2016-08-20 18:15:00
3   EMP0002         check_in        2016-08-21 14:52:48
4   EMP0002         check_out       2016-08-21 21:09:18
```

**Query**

```
SELECT 
  A1.employee_code,
  A1.created AS check_in_at,
  A2.created AS check_out_at,
  TIMEDIFF(A2.created, A1.created) AS total_time 
FROM
  tbl_attendances AS A1 
  INNER JOIN tbl_attendances AS A2 
    ON A1.employee_code = A2.employee_code 
    AND DATE(A1.created) = DATE(A2.created) 
WHERE 1 = 1 
  AND A1.status = 'check_in' 
  AND A2.status = 'check_out' 
  AND DATE(A1.created) BETWEEN '2016-08-20' 
  AND '2016-08-21' 
  AND DATE(A2.created) BETWEEN '2016-08-20' 
  AND '2016-08-21' 
ORDER BY A1.created DESC
```

**Results**

```
employee_code   check_in_at            check_out_at           total_time

EMP0002         2016-08-21 14:52:48    2016-08-21 21:09:18    06:16:30
EMP0001         2016-08-20 09:30:30    2016-08-20 18:15:00    08:44:30
```

For specific employee add `AND A1.employee_code = 'EMP0001'` in `WHERE` clause

Comment: Sorry but this does not work for me , I have tested your solution and I got false informations , could you please edit your code??!!!!

Comment: @csharp_devloper31 Can you elaborate further?? so I know what issues you are facing and fix my answer accordingly.

Comment: this only produce result when there is check_out record on that day right?

Answer (score 3):

### Format #2 is better because :

1. This table is just a punch record entry - Even if it has anomalies it doesn't matter.
2. Going forward this table will expand, for example you might want to introduce two more events INTERVAL_OUT, INTERVAL_IN. Second format will keep it simple.
3. If possible use event_type_id instead of event_type and another table event_type or just a constant array eg.

   array_event_name = array (1=>CHECKIN, 2=>CHECKOUT, 3=>INTERVAL_IN, 4=>INTERVAL_OUT)

Answer (score 1):

i would go with the second one.

however, the main questions and business rules will be the same and answerable by either approach.

Answer (score 1):

### Option #1

With the first option, the database itself can better protect itself from some anomalies<sup>1</sup>. Some anomalies are still possible<sup>2</sup>, but it's a start.

*On the other hand*, InnoDB tables are clustered and secondary indexes in clustered tables can be expensive (see the "Disadvantages of clustering" in [this article](http://www.ovaistariq.net/521/understanding-innodb-clustered-indexes/)), which is something to consider if you need to query on `check_out`.

### Option #2

With the second option, you are relying on the imperative code even for anomalies that can be prevented purely declaratively with the database design.

On a plus side, you are less likely to need secondary indexes.

### Choice

So in a nutshell, go with the first option, unless you need a secondary index. If you do need the secondary index, depending on what kind of [index covering](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/glossary/covering-index) you wish to achieve, you might go with either option.

---

*<sup>1</sup> Such as checking-out without first checking-in.*

*<sup>2</sup> Such as checking-in again, without first checking-out, overlapping "stints", etc...*

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the first option here. Putting both time stamps in a single row will enhance your search time and will make your calculations easier.

Suppose you want to calculation work hours for an employee for a day. Your search will stop at the first line it matches and you will have all the required data. You wont have to dig any deeper which is not the case with option 2. Option 1 also reduces your table size by using only 1 row per check-in/check-out.

Option 2 does have one advantage though. When checking out, your database will have to do a search to update the data for option 1. For option 2, its just a write.

Considering the fact that you will search the data more than once, you can give up the direct insert advantage to gain a better structure and faster search. Although the final choice is up to you.

Good Luck!